# SSAS processing timeout at 60 minutes

Tags: timeout, ssas

we are facing an issue on our production SSAS server : any process is timeouting after 60 minutes. I cannot find the root cause of why it is happening - in the properties, there is not (anymore) any configuration value set at 60 minutes - most notably, the ExternalTimeoutCommand property is increased from the default 3600 seconds to 7200 seconds.

It is not one query running for 60 minutes, it is xmla batches. On our integration server they are working, and I see no legitimate reason why it shouldn't run on production (i.e. why should the timeout be 60 minutes and not for example 64 minutes? it doesn't have any practical justification), I just cannot find where/how to change the configuration to make it work on there as well. Somebody please advise:)

Thank you, 
Aleš

Comment: Are the XMLA requests sent in from an external application, and if so do they set the CommitTimeout property or otherwise in their connection strings?

Comment: the timeout happens regardless of how the processing is triggered. whether it is ran by a job or manually, it gets killed after 60 minutes